# What are the strange characters at the end of the html in the clipboard after copy/pasting from Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, clipboard, copy-paste

When I copy some text from an MS Outlook email and paste it into a contenteditable element (in Chrome), the `clipboardData` property of the paste event contains HTML that ends with some weird characters. It looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
...
<!--StartFragment-->
...
<!--EndFragment-->
...
</body>
</html>
orati�o<�z�
```

The characters at the end are different each time, but they are always present.

I was wondering why these characters are there. Do they have any special meaning?

(Note that this does **not** seem to be an encoding issue: everything *between* the `<html>` tags looks valid and does not contain strange characters.)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the Outlook email is encoded using a different character set to the editor you are pasting into; e.g. If the email is UTF-8 encoded and you paste into an ISO-8859 document then these replacement characters appear to represent those not recognized by ISO-8859.

As clearlight says, with the  chars being at the end, this could be just buffer garbage. Try right-clicking the email and viewing source to determine if the html is well formed. Alternatively try forwarding the email to another address and viewing the source in another email client. This will confirm if its outlook or not.

Comment: Why are the characters all *after* the valid HTML then and not interspersed with it. It's probably just a bug in outlook. Garbage in the buffer that their own client knows how to ignore or use that they didn't bother to handle properly for exposure to the world  Anyway @RaghubendraSingh (another answer) is probably right, if it's consistently like that, what else can be done except ignore?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply ignore them, they don't have to do anything with the HTML code.

Check [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/strange-characterssymbols-in-returned-emails/be19f983-27cc-4d61-99d1-f94a372ef31c) link for reference.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Outlook but still it would be better to have a definitive answer and also verify these junk characters are the same ones seen sending emails.

Comment: The link you referenced claims this is an encoding issue, but I don't think that this applies here. The HTML itself is valid and does not contain strange characters; the strange characters appear _after_ the </html> tag.